# How can I initialize high order tensor in Julia?

Tags: julia

I would like to define n-th order tensor X in Julia.

When n is small, we can define i[1]×i[2]×…×[n] tensor as

```
X = rand(i[1],i[2],i[3])
```

or

```
X = Array{Float64, 3}(undef, i[1], i[2], i[3])
```

These examples are in case of n=3.
But when n is large and list i is given, how can I define high order tensor??

**EDIT**

I found heuristics answer.

```
using TensorToolbox
i = [3,4,2,5,4,1,3]
X = diagt(i)
```

Is this best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this?

```
rand(i...)
```

or that?

```
Array{Float64}(undef, i...)
```